# HttpClient Angular 5 does not send request

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript, httpclient, angular5

I have a problem with HttpClient in Angular 5. HttpClient does not send any request (I don't see any xhr log in console) on two specified components. On the others components everything is fine.

Calling ApiService POST method (custom service which works like a wrapper for HttpClient) from Component **A**, but when I call this method from Component **B** 
HttpClient seems to be frozen.

There are many components in my app that use ApiService. Everything is injected fine. I have no idea what is wrong.

--- respond

ApiService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService
{
    private errorListeners : Map<string, Array<(details ?: any) => any>> =
        new Map<string, Array<(details ?: any) => any>>();

    public constructor(private http: HttpClient)
    {

    }

    public post<T>(path : string, data : any, urlParams : any = null) : Observable<any>
    {
        return this.http.post<T>(`${environment.api.path}${path}`, data, {
            params: urlParams
        }).catch(this.catchErrors()).map(response => {
            if (response['Error']){
                throw response['Error'];
            }

            return response;
        });
    }

}
```

-- 
Component

```
   @Component({
    selector: 'login-register-component',
    templateUrl: './register.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        './../../assets/main/css/pages/login.css'
    ]
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{

public constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
                       private router: Router,
                       private userService : UserService,
                       private apiService: ApiService
    )
    {
        this.apiService.post('/some-endpoint', null, {}).subscribe(res => {
console.log(res);
```

});

```
}
```

HttpClient does not work even if i directly inject HttpClient into Component

-- Other component in the same module
example call: (it works)

```
public loginTraditionalMethod(emailAddress : string, plainPassword : string)
    {

        this.apiService.post('/auth/email', {
            email: emailAddress,
            password: plainPassword
        }, {}).subscribe(res => {
           console.log(res);
        })

    }
```

Comment: shoe some how: the http call in your service, and how you call your service in your components

Comment: @David i edited post

Comment: How do you call service in the other component? Can you post call for components A and B?

Comment: @David i added a sample of code where service's method is called

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: What was it? I could not figure it out. Was your error handler hiding the error ?

Comment: I slipped. In component instead of call *subscribe()* I used *map()*. I also made a mistake in sample code at post above, i didn't copy a code, i rewrote it, after a while i saw that  i made a mistake at original code. So the code above is correct and seems to be working. Sorry for the trouble but thanks for help. I took me 3 hours to saw this stupid miss

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem, no xhr request after subscribing to a `http.get()`. This was a request for a forgotten password function, I was therefore not connected to the app.

The request was being intercepted by an http token interceptor that was returning an empty Observable if no session was detected.

Never know, this might help someone...

Comment: Thank you kind stranger! This was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Where is this "http token interceptor"? In the app, or on the API server? Can you post some code?

Comment: The token interceptor is client side and looks somthing like this : https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8 

The following bit of code was stopping any requests from being dispatched if we weren't authenticated : 


`if (!this.session.isAuthenticated() && !this.session.isFetching()) {
this.session.dispatchSessionLost();
return Observable.empty(); 
}`